# Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: mysql

Okay so im having this annying error when im trying typing in my username and password anyone know the problem ?

The error : http://gyazo.com/9ee7a24d164be385c499a2bf82022720
My database: http://gyazo.com/4524567fd304d4181ce0c82f8e715ea8

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<p>
<?php
if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST')
{
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'databasename', 'password');
if (!$link) 
{
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('databasename', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
$query = "SELECT username, pass FROM hejsan where ='".$_POST['username'] ."' and  pass      ='".$_POST['pass']."' 
LIMIT 0, 30 ";
echo $query;
echo "<br><br>";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) 
{
$message = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
$message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
die($message);
}
echo "<ul>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
echo "<li>";
echo "Inloggad som:". $row['username']." med lösen:".$row['pass'];
echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
mysql_free_result($result);
}
?>
<form method="POST">
Username:<input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password:<input type="text" name="pass"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the field in your query.

It should be

```
"SELECT username, pass FROM hejsan where ***username*** ='".$_POST['username'] ."' and  pass      ='".$_POST['pass']."'
```

LIMIT 0, 30 ";

where ***username*** is the field where usernames are stored.

Comment: I have one more question do you know how to it possible to see all the users fom the database hijacking it ?

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php.   Basically, if the user enter j' OR 1=1;-- as their username, they can potentially get all the records on your hejsan table.

Comment: I have read but i don't really understand that much, litterally exacly what do i write in username and password to contain all the inforamtion from table "hejsan" ?

Comment: Did you put that whole string in the username field?